# Howto ellipsis-parameter in Scheme (STK)

Tags: scheme

probably an easy question: I want to wrap the "(format ..)" function of Scheme in order to handle my debugging output (including the wrapping of the format-string).

As "format" takes a variable number of arguments my wrapper would need to do that too yielding the question on how I tell scheme to have an ellipsis-parameter and how to reference it.

I thought of something like this:

```
(define debugPrint
    (lambda (formatString ELLIPSIS_PARAMETER)
        (if debug
            (format #t (string-append "<!--" formatString "-->") ELLIPSIS_PARAMETER)
            ()
        )
    )
)
```

Thank You for your help in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is dot notation for this:

```
(define (debugPrint formatString . params)
 (if debug
   (apply format #t (string-append "<!--" formatString "-->") params)
   '()))
```

Take note on `apply` as dot notation wraps all parameters in list and when you use `(debugPrint "~a: ~a" key name)`, the `formatString` will be bound to `"~a: ~a"` and `params` will be bound to `(key name)` (sure the values of key and name, not symbols ;).

Comment: Ahh, that way it goes :) - additionally the notation without lambda is not bad. I should have read a tutorial on how to write scheme instead of just reading code of other people ;)